# 3com Vlan setup

Tags: networking, vlan, network-monitoring

I am setting up a vlan on my 3com switch. The switch is a 4200g 48 port.

I have set up 3 vlans i have the generic vlan1 and I have created 2 other vlans 2 and 3.

I have manually give them their ip range. However when I connect a device to the ports that have been setup for the vlans it does not connect to the network. Should this happen when a device is attached the vlans that i have setup?

Has anyone on here had any experience on setting up a vlan on a 3com switch?

Comment: When you say "it does not connect to the network", what does that mean? You've made three networks. When you connect a device to a port in VLAN 2, then it should connect to the VLAN 2 network. The VLANs won't be able to talk to each other unless you've arranged it somehow, such as with an inter-VLAN router.

Comment: will the vlans however be able to use network resources such as internet and acccess servers?

Comment: If you make arrangements for them to do so, then yes. If not, then no. But if you don't have anything routing packets between those VLANs and the Internet, don't expect those networks to have Internet access. It can't work by magic.

Comment: Cheers David thats alot of help

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the port mode. 
A VLAN is a seperate network. You should put a port in 'access' mode on the switch when connecting a host. Trunk mode to connect 2 switches and allow traffic of multiple vlan's over the port.

The host should be in the same network as other hosts in that vlan. A vlan does not work as DHCP server. So hosts will have to find a DHCP in the same vlan or have static IP's.

Try giving the hosts a static ip. Connect the host to a port that has been set-up in the correct VLAN. Then try to ping the VLAN ip of the switch.

Also, keep in mind that it takes a few seconds for the switch port to go into forwarding state ( sometimes you can see this by the LED's going from orange to green). This might take up to 30 - 45 seconds after plugging in the LAN cable.

Comment: Hi i have all the host ports set as access. However i do have the port that is being used as uplink set as trunk.